# fuzzy outer join/merge in R

Tags: r, data.table, outer-join, fuzzy-logic, fuzzyjoin

I have 2 datasets and want to do fuzzy join.
Here is the two datasets.

```
library(data.table)
# data1
dt1 <- fread("NAME                State type
              ABERCOMBIE TOWNSHIP   ND  TS
              ABERDEEN TOWNSHIP     NJ  TS
              ABERDEEN TOWNSHIP     SD  TS
              ABBOTSFORD CITY       WI  CI
              ABERDEEN CITY         WA  CI
              ADA TOWNSHIP          MI  TS
              ADAMS                 IL  TS", header = T)
# data2
dt2 <- fread("NAME               State  type
              ABERDEEN TWP N J    NJ    TS
              ABERDEEN WASH       WA    CI
              ABBOTSFORD WIS      WI    CI
              ADA TWP MICH        MI    TS
              ADA OHIO            OH    CI
              ADAMS MASS          MA    CI
              ADAMSVILLE ALA      AL    CI", header = T)
```

Two datasets have the same characters in `State` and `type`; however, columns `NAME` are not the same. They are similar.
Although I can subtract columns `NAME` on each data with 3 or 4 charters and then merge them, it seems that the correct ratio may not high due to large observations.

```
dt1$NameSubstr <- substr(dt1$NAME, 1, 4)
dt2$NameSubstr <- substr(dt2$NAME, 1, 4)
merge(dt1, dt2, by = c("NameSubstr", "State", "type"), all = T)
```

The method is bad.

I check for package `fuzzyjoin`. But not sure whether I am correct or not.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_full_join(dt1, dt2, by = c("NAME" = "NAME", "State" = "State", "type" = "type"), match_fun = list(`!=`, `==`, `==`))  

# Results
                 NAME.x State.x type.x           NAME.y State.y type.y
 1:   ABERDEEN TOWNSHIP      NJ     TS ABERDEEN TWP N J      NJ     TS
 2:     ABBOTSFORD CITY      WI     CI   ABBOTSFORD WIS      WI     CI
 3:       ABERDEEN CITY      WA     CI    ABERDEEN WASH      WA     CI
 4:        ADA TOWNSHIP      MI     TS     ADA TWP MICH      MI     TS
 5: ABERCOMBIE TOWNSHIP      ND     TS             <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
 6:   ABERDEEN TOWNSHIP      SD     TS             <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
 7:               ADAMS      IL     TS             <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
 8:                <NA>    <NA>   <NA>         ADA OHIO      OH     CI
 9:                <NA>    <NA>   <NA>       ADAMS MASS      MA     CI
10:                <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   ADAMSVILLE ALA      AL     CI
```

The result in this exercise is correct, see below. But If any NAME in these two data are the same, the answer will not correct.
I create a new observation in these two data.

```
dt1 <- fread("NAME  State   type
         ABERCOMBIE TOWNSHIP    ND  TS
         ABERDEEN TOWNSHIP  NJ  TS
         ABERDEEN TOWNSHIP  SD  TS
         ABBOTSFORD CITY    WI  CI
         ABERDEEN CITY  WA  CI
         ADA TOWNSHIP   MI  TS
         ADAMS  IL  TS
         THE SAME   AA  BB
         ", header = T)
dt2 <- fread("NAME  State   type
         ABERDEEN TWP N J   NJ  TS
         ABERDEEN WASH  WA  CI
         ABBOTSFORD WIS WI  CI
         ADA TWP MICH   MI  TS
         ADA OHIO   OH  CI
         ADAMS MASS MA  CI
         ADAMSVILLE ALA AL  CI
         THE SAME   AA  BB
         ", header = T)

fuzzy_full_join(dt1, dt2, by = c("NAME" = "NAME", "State" = "State", "type" = "type"), match_fun = list(`!=`, `==`, `==`))

                 NAME.x State.x type.x           NAME.y State.y type.y
 1:   ABERDEEN TOWNSHIP      NJ     TS ABERDEEN TWP N J      NJ     TS
 2:     ABBOTSFORD CITY      WI     CI   ABBOTSFORD WIS      WI     CI
 3:       ABERDEEN CITY      WA     CI    ABERDEEN WASH      WA     CI
 4:        ADA TOWNSHIP      MI     TS     ADA TWP MICH      MI     TS
 5: ABERCOMBIE TOWNSHIP      ND     TS             <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
 6:   ABERDEEN TOWNSHIP      SD     TS             <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
 7:               ADAMS      IL     TS             <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
 8:            THE SAME      AA     BB             <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
 9:                <NA>    <NA>   <NA>         ADA OHIO      OH     CI
10:                <NA>    <NA>   <NA>       ADAMS MASS      MA     CI
11:                <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   ADAMSVILLE ALA      AL     CI
12:                <NA>    <NA>   <NA>         THE SAME      AA     BB
```

This is incorrect result.
Any suggestion?

It seems that I cannot use `fuzzy_full_join`.

Comment: Hi. This is not clear. Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes expected output for problem input & a clear description of what rows output based on what rows are in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you asked fuzzy_full_join to give you NAMES that did not match (with !=) and then state and types that did match (with == ==). So if in the case all three do match, it won't show up.

You could run it twice with:

```
match_fun = list(`!=`, `==`, `==`))
match_fun = list(`==`, `==`, `==`))
```

```r
library(data.table); library(fuzzyjoin)
#> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 3.5.2

dt1 <- fread("NAME   State   type
             ABERCOMBIETOWNSHIP    ND  TS
             ABERDEENTOWNSHIP  NJ  TS
             ABERDEENTOWNSHIP  SD  TS
             ABBOTSFORDCITY    WI  CI
             ABERDEENCITY  WA  CI
             ADATOWNSHIP   MI  TS
             ADAMS IL  TS
             THESAME   AA  BB
             ", header = T)
dt2 <- fread("NAME  State   type
             ABERDEENTWPNJ   NJ  TS
             ABERDEENWASH  WA  CI
             ABBOTSFORDWIS WI  CI
             ADATWPMICH   MI  TS
             ADAOHIO   OH  CI
             ADAMSMASS MA  CI
             ADAMSVILLEALA AL  CI
             THESAME   AA  BB
             ", header = T)

fuzzy_full_join(dt1, dt2, by = c("NAME" = "NAME", "State" = "State", "type" = "type"), match_fun = list(`!=`, `==`, `==`))
#>                 NAME.x State.x type.x        NAME.y State.y type.y
#>  1:   ABERDEENTOWNSHIP      NJ     TS ABERDEENTWPNJ      NJ     TS
#>  2:     ABBOTSFORDCITY      WI     CI ABBOTSFORDWIS      WI     CI
#>  3:       ABERDEENCITY      WA     CI  ABERDEENWASH      WA     CI
#>  4:        ADATOWNSHIP      MI     TS    ADATWPMICH      MI     TS
#>  5: ABERCOMBIETOWNSHIP      ND     TS          <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
#>  6:   ABERDEENTOWNSHIP      SD     TS          <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
#>  7:              ADAMS      IL     TS          <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
#>  8:            THESAME      AA     BB          <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
#>  9:               <NA>    <NA>   <NA>       ADAOHIO      OH     CI
#> 10:               <NA>    <NA>   <NA>     ADAMSMASS      MA     CI
#> 11:               <NA>    <NA>   <NA> ADAMSVILLEALA      AL     CI
#> 12:               <NA>    <NA>   <NA>       THESAME      AA     BB

fuzzy_full_join(dt1, dt2, by = c("NAME" = "NAME", "State" = "State", "type" = "type"), match_fun = list(`==`, `==`, `==`))
#>                 NAME.x State.x type.x        NAME.y State.y type.y
#>  1:            THESAME      AA     BB       THESAME      AA     BB
#>  2: ABERCOMBIETOWNSHIP      ND     TS          <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
#>  3:   ABERDEENTOWNSHIP      NJ     TS          <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
#>  4:   ABERDEENTOWNSHIP      SD     TS          <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
#>  5:     ABBOTSFORDCITY      WI     CI          <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
#>  6:       ABERDEENCITY      WA     CI          <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
#>  7:        ADATOWNSHIP      MI     TS          <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
#>  8:              ADAMS      IL     TS          <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
#>  9:               <NA>    <NA>   <NA> ABERDEENTWPNJ      NJ     TS
#> 10:               <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  ABERDEENWASH      WA     CI
#> 11:               <NA>    <NA>   <NA> ABBOTSFORDWIS      WI     CI
#> 12:               <NA>    <NA>   <NA>    ADATWPMICH      MI     TS
#> 13:               <NA>    <NA>   <NA>       ADAOHIO      OH     CI
#> 14:               <NA>    <NA>   <NA>     ADAMSMASS      MA     CI
#> 15:               <NA>    <NA>   <NA> ADAMSVILLEALA      AL     CI
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>